# Argument expression expected and Declaration or statement expected

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I have two errors on this code

The first error is **Argument expression expected** in last }.
The second error is **Declaration or statement expected** in the last ).
It can be the unfinished { and ( but I can't find an unfinished one.

```
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    } else if (command === 'help') {
        message.channel.send({ embed: {
            color: 16758465,
            title: "You want help?",
            description: ":sparkles:Hi! I'm Ohi bot owned by ilkoshu.",
            fields: [{
                name: ":fish_cake:Bot Commands",
                value: "..commands"
              },
              {
                name: ":strawberry:Contact Me",
                value: "..contact"
              },
            ],
            timestamp: new Date(),
          }
        });
    }
    else if(command === "commands"){
      message.channel.send({ embed: {
        color: 16758465,
        title: "Bot Commands",
        fields: [{
            name: ":birthday:Fun Commands",
            value: "..dice, ..avatar, ..meme, ..say, ..animesuggest, ..top15animech, ..guessage"
          },
          {
            name: ":mushroom:Roleplay Commands",
            value: "..hug [user], ..pat [user], ..kiss [user], ..cuddle [user], ..greet [user], ..bite [user], ..slap [user], ..punch [user], ..kill [user], ..run, ..cry, ..smile, ..dance"
          },
          {
            name: ":shaved_ice:Admin Commands",
            value: "..ban [user], ..kick [user], ..voicemute [user], ..clear [2-20], ..serverinfo"
          },
          {
            name: ":chocolate_bar:About Bot",
            value: "..ping, ..botinfo, ..vote, ..invite"
          }],
        },
      },
//...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you were having was due to the commas `,` and the parenthesis `)` misplaced. First of all, you shouldn't be placing commas to close functions, unless you are calling a new one after. You were not closing in any parenthesis for this line `message.channel.send({ embed: {`, which was causing 1 error. The other error was due to the comma present on the first line of the following example:

```
      },
//...
});
```

After removing the commas and placing the parenthesis on the right line, your code will end up being the following:

```
if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('Pong.');
} else if (command === 'help') {
    message.channel.send({ embed: {
        color: 16758465,
        title: "You want help?",
        description: ":sparkles:Hi! I'm Ohi bot owned by ilkoshu.",
        fields: [{
            name: ":fish_cake:Bot Commands",
            value: "..commands"
          },
          {
            name: ":strawberry:Contact Me",
            value: "..contact"
          },
        ],
        timestamp: new Date(),
      }
    });
}
else if(command === "commands"){
  message.channel.send({ embed: {
    color: 16758465,
    title: "Bot Commands",
    fields: [{
        name: ":birthday:Fun Commands",
        value: "..dice, ..avatar, ..meme, ..say, ..animesuggest, ..top15animech, ..guessage"
      },
      {
        name: ":mushroom:Roleplay Commands",
        value: "..hug [user], ..pat [user], ..kiss [user], ..cuddle [user], ..greet [user], ..bite [user], ..slap [user], ..punch [user], ..kill [user], ..run, ..cry, ..smile, ..dance"
      },
      {
        name: ":shaved_ice:Admin Commands",
        value: "..ban [user], ..kick [user], ..voicemute [user], ..clear [2-20], ..serverinfo"
      },
      {
        name: ":chocolate_bar:About Bot",
        value: "..ping, ..botinfo, ..vote, ..invite"
      }]
    }
  })
}
```

I hope it helped, and best of luck with your coding!